# How to solve the below scenario?

Tags: summation

How can extract the individual no from its total sum for below case ?

$$
 2^1+2^3+2^4+2^8+2^{13}+2^{17}=139546
$$

in the above expression i have only value **139546** but no knowledge about no of number in left hand side in this case how can extract the individual numbers like $$ 2^1, 2^3, 2^4, ^8, 2^{13}, 2^{17}$$ from total sum **139546**.

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the binary representation of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Binary.html). Specifically here is an algorithm for finding it:

```
if (n == 0) then
    return (0)
end
k = floor(log_2(n))
a_k = 1
n = n - 2^k
k = k - 1
while n > 0
    if (n >= 2^k) then
        n = n - 2^k
        a_k = 1
    else
        a_k = 0
    end
    k = k - 1
end
return a = (a_0, ..., a_k)
```

Then
$$n = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i 2^i$$
so your numbers are precisely the $2^i$ for wich $a_i = 1$.